# How to know you have web enabled phone or not?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, smartphone

Currently i m working on a facebook application. I have to know user have web enabled smart phone or not. How can i know that user have web enabled phone or not from facebook api.

Hint: If user have web enabled phone they have activated it on facebook to use facebook on there phone.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question here?

Comment: I want to know user have mobile device or not using facebook.

Comment: The Graph API `user` object has a field called `devices`.

Answer (score 0):

[This php class](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) is pretty good for a whole range of device detections.

You can find some examples on how to use it on that site too

Comment: I want to know user have mobile device or not using facebook. not he is from mobile or browser